# PHP - Reverse Search By Key Using ArraySearch

Tags: php, arrays

I really like to messing around with arrays.
From the [official link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), array_search is :

```
Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
```

If I have a case like this :

```
 $bill = [
            '<label class="label label-default">Cleaning</label>'      => 1,
            '<label class="label label-success">One Bar</label>'       => 2,
            '<label class="label label-warning">Test Periodic</label>' => 3,
            '<label class="label label-primary">Repairs</label>'       => 4,
        ];
 return array_search($data['tagihan'], $bill);
```

Let say, I have a `$data['tagihan'] = 1`, then It will be return

```
<label class="label label-default">Cleaning</label>
```

Now, how if I have an array like this :

```
 $bill = [
            1 => '<label class="label label-default">Cleaning</label>',
            2 => '<label class="label label-success">One Bar</label>',
            3 => '<label class="label label-warning">Test Periodic</label>',
            4 => '<label class="label label-primary">Repairs</label>',
        ];
```

How can I still get `<label class="label label-default">Cleaning</label>`
which is `$data['tagihan'] = 1`

Comment: '$bill[$data[tagihan]]' ... or miss I something?

Comment: Seems like you wouldn't really need a function. You could just use `$bill[$data['tagihan']]`. (Probably should check if it's set first.)

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the key of the array using the search value, if it exists:

```
echo $bill[$data['tagihan']];
```

Or a function as you should at least check if it exists:

```
function array_key_search($needle, $haystack) {
    if(isset($haystack[$needle])) {
        return $haystack[$needle];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you just missed something. I am able to get the expected result with `$bill[$date['tagihan']]`.